# unable to assign ad role global reader in azure cloud terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

Trying to assign global reader role and getting below error in terraform-

```
  │ Error: Invalid resource type
    │ 
    │   on ../../modules/infrastructure/cloud-scanner-app/main.tf line 51, in resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "example":
    │   51: resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "example" {
    │ 
    │ The provider hashicorp/azuread does not support resource type "azuread_directory_role_assignment"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I guess that you are using a hashicorp/azuread provider version older than 2.25.0. The resource type azuread_directory_role_assignment was introduced in 2.25.0 (June 23, 2022). I suggest upgrading the provider to at least 2.26.1 because as you can see in the changelog, some bugfixes for the azuread_directory_role_assignment resource type have been made: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks. Bumping the version fixed it.